# Iteration of arrays and objects in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Schema.js

```
var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
  type: String,
  index: true
},
 path: {
   type: String
 },
 originalname: {
   type: String
 }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('Item',ItemSchema, 'iteminfo');
```

route.js

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  Item.find({},function(err, docs){
                res.render('welcome', {docs:docs});
        });
});
```

index.hbs

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    [list of data here!!!]
  </body>
</html>
```

Is my code in routes correct? how to display all data in `index.js`? Help please. I am a newbie in `node.js` and `mongoDB`. Thanks :)

In mongo shell, when I hit `db.users.find()`, It has two collections. I want the desired output to be like this in index

```
username = "username1"
path = "path1"
originalname = "originalname1"


username = "username2"
path = "path2"
originalname = "originalname2"
```

Is it possible? Like doing some `foreach` concept.

Comment: which template engine are you using

Comment: I used handlebars. That's index.handlebars

Comment: not index.js. Sorry my bad.

Comment: I tried {{docs}} in my index.handlebars. The data shows but it is in array form. I want something like foreach in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your .hbs file

> You can iterate over a list using the built-in each helper. Inside the block, you can use this to reference the element being iterated over.

```
<ul class="people_list">
  {{#each docs}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and for docs with objects inside array

`[{}, {}, {}]`

```
<ul class="people_list">
  {{#each docs}} // iterating over array, and #each below loops the properties of elements {}
    <li> {{#each this}} </li>  
       {{this}} // references the property values
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Docs are Here

[**`Iteration in Handlebars`**](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration)

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider you have 2 fields in you model. Name and _id. You need to render that to the views.

Here you need 'ejs' module, a templating framework to render the data in the html.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Keep all the views inside the 'parentfolder/views'..

routes.js

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
Item.find({},function(err, docs){
            res.render('welcome', {docs:docs});  // here the welcome should be the file name of the html you need to render
    });
});
```

welcome.html

```
<table>
  <% for(var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= docs[i].id %></td>
    <td><%= docs[i].name %></td>
   </tr>
  <% } %>
</table>
```

Here is the [ejs](http://ejs.co/) syntax.

Your sample output will be like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>bob</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>john</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>jake</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: @LawrenceRicafortBacus Above code is for `.ejs` you said you are using handlebars,
http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration

Comment: @p0k8_ He mentioned he is newbie so he just need some solution regardless of the templating framework. If is in middle of a large project with handlebars implementation is done he would have mentioned it clearly.

Comment: @Prasanthchinja if there is no exact solution to the question, then you could do this, finding alternative ways. Please Update your answer using handlebars, this is for the community, not only for OP

Comment: data is not defined? Plus it destroys the previous template. Why?

Comment: Is there any solution that uses handlebars?

Comment: @LawrenceRicafortBacus please try the below answer, and please refer the docs

Answer (score 0):

This is my example, in this case I am iterating a body table

```
{{#each campaign}}
  <tr>
   <td>{{this}}</td>
   <td>{{this._id.campaign}}</td>
   <td>{{this.quantity}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```